# Call child method in parent's method?

Tags: java

I want to use a method from a child class in the method of a parent class, is it possible?

```
class Parent{
    public Parent() {   }

    public void methodParent () { 
        methodChild();       
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {    
    public Child() {
        super();
    }

    public void methodChild() {
        //do somthing
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to implement inheritance in such a poor way?

Comment: I'm new in java , I don't know how could I do

Comment: This question has answered several times. Please search for exiting questions before asking new one.

Answer (score -1):

the class parent will can not find the method methodChild(),it doesn't exist when you bulid instance of classs parent